# How is SwiftUI able to use string literals in Text to create a LocalizedStringKey?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to have my custom views work like Text. If I pass a string literal, I would like it to be created using LocalizedStringKey, and if I pass a variable, I would like it to be treated as a String (likewise with verbatim:). I did a little test, and using the same signatures on init as Text, if I pass a literal, it goes to the StringProtocol init. How is this done with Text?

Comment: You mean, how come it works for a ```Text``` view? If you go to an example like ```Text("hello")``` and hit Ctrl+Command+J in Xcode (or Navigate > Jump to Definition) then you will see that the definition has a "_semantics" attribute. I'm guessing that this is part of SwiftUI internal magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did a little test, and using the same signatures on init as Text, if I pass a literal, it goes to the StringProtocol init.

I suppose you did something like this:

```
init<S: StringProtocol>(_ x: S) {}
init(_ x: LocalizedStringKey) {}
```

And you found that the first overload is always being called.

This can be fixed by marking the `StringProtocol` overload with `@_disfavoredOverload`. Note that since this has an underscore prefix, it is not a stable feature and might change in the future.

But this is indeed what `Text` in SwiftUI uses (at least for now). `@_disflavoredOverload` is documented in [this markdown file](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/ReferenceGuides/UnderscoredAttributes.md#_disfavoredoverload). The example there shows this exact problem with `LocalizableStringKey`:

> ```
> extension LocalizedStringKey: ExpressibleByStringLiteral { ... }
>
> extension Text {
>   // We want `Text("foo")` to use this initializer:
>   init(_ key: LocalizedStringKey) { ... }
>
>   // But without @_disfavoredOverload, it would use this one instead,
>   // because that lets it give the literal its default type:
>   @_disfavoredOverload init<S: StringProtocol>(_ str: S) { ... }
> }
> ```